# How to pass url params to Django model filter with list of values per param

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to pass url param values to Django model filter here is my sample url `https://www.example.com/api/organization?id=5&status=0,1&class=4,5`

Here is my code.

```
def set_if_not_none(self, mapping, key, value):
    if value is not None:
        mapping[key] = value

def get_org_list(self, status, id, format=None):

    filter_params = {}
    self.set_if_not_none(filter_params, "is_active", status)
    self.set_if_not_none(filter_params, "org_id", id)

    queryset = Organization.objects.filter(**filter_params).order_by("org_name")
```

Error :

> ValueError: Field 'is_active' expected a number but got '0,1'.

How to fix this

Comment: Have you tried passing the argument twice with different values? Like `status=0&status=1`?

Comment: @GwynBleidD , if pass the status=1, then it works.. it is not working only if we pass arguments with comma Eg. status=0,1